# Flourish PHP Library - Cryptology Security

Tags: php, flourishlib

I am looking at switching to [Flourish](http://flourishlib.com) but am concerned with its current state of development. It is in beta, but they say that it "can generally be considered production ready." I am looking through the documentation and am not sure if the [cryptology](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fCryptography) portion of the framework is secure enough for every day use.

Has anyone worked with Flourish, specifically the cryptology APIs and have an option on its viability.

Comment: Well, ask your security consultant, not just on a website.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, yes, it's perfectly secure. Very good library. Trust me!